# Disappear/disabled few Jenkins parameters in build parameters based on the other Boolean param is true

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Could you please provide the solution for disabling/disappearing the 'AWS' string parameter in the build parameters section when the Boolean Param is true? and Similarly, we have a list of parameters that will disappear when we click a boolean parameter is true and below is the example code.

```
pipeline{ 
        parameters { 
            booleanParam(name: 'deploy' defaultValue: false)  
            string( name: 'Azure' defaultValue: '')
            string( name: 'Aws' defaultValue: '')
        } 
        stages{
            stage('build') {
             steps{
                 script { 
                    echo 'Running.' 
                    } 
                }
             } 
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same thing and used Active Choices https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/

It doesn't hide the field headers, but it "disables" them by not returning the input box.

```
pipeline {
  parameters {
    activeChoiceParam('deploy') {
      choiceType('RADIO')
      groovyScript {
        script("return ['true', 'false']")
        fallbackScript("return ['error']")
      }
    }
    stringParam('Azure', '', '')
    activeChoiceReactiveReferenceParam('Aws') {
      choiceType('FORMATTED_HTML')
      groovyScript {
        script('''
        if (!deploy.equals('true')) {
          return  "<input name='Aws' value='' class='setting-input' type='text'>"
        }
        '''
        )
        fallbackScript("return ['error']")
      }
      referencedParameter('deploy')
    }
}
  stages{
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        script {
          echo 'Running.'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[deploy true pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdAqE.png)

[deploy false pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHxS7.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in current version of Jenkins.

Comment: Okay, then how can we achieve this, is there any alternate method by using groovy script